# SQL How to add new columns each time I run my code

Tags: sql, sas

I would like that every time I run the code, the POLICY_VINTAGE dataset would add count (NRB) result from processing as another column called eg Week2 and next week3. Is there any additional feature in SAS for that?

```
PROC SQL;   
   create table POLICY_VINTAGE as
   select distinct 
   POLICY_VINTAGE
  ,count(NRB) as Week1
   from PolisyEnd
   where POLIS ="A"
   group by 
   POLICY_VINTAGE

;
Quit;
data POLICY_VINTAGE ;
set _work.POLICY_VINTAGE 
;
run;
```

Comment: It looks like you need to historize your data, but why don't you have an kind of 'historization date' that would change each week, rather than a new column? To use historized data, it'll be much easier

Comment: Could you give me some examp;le how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to merge your historical dataset with the new dataset. It would be much more efficient to store your historical data in a long format, and present it in a wide format as needed.

First, to answer your question, let's create some code that does exactly what you asked. Your initial historical dataset will be called `policy_vintage_historical`, and all new data will merge to it.

Since you would be modifying a permanent dataset by merging things to it, it may be a good idea to use the `genmax` option to create backups of your dataset automatically. Keep in mind, if your dataset is big, this may not be feasible and you do not want to use this.

```
data lib.policy_vintage_historical;
    merge lib.policy_vintage_historical
              policy_vintage
    ;

    by policy_vintage;
run;
```

A more efficient way: store it in a long format. Note that the week number needs to dynamically be generated. You can do this in any way you'd like.

The code below will calculate the total, then append it to a long dataset.

```
PROC SQL;   
   create table POLICY_VINTAGE as
       select distinct 
            POLICY_VINTAGE
          , 1 as week
          , count(nrb) as total
       from PolisyEnd
       where POLIS ="A"
       group by 
       POLICY_VINTAGE
quit;

proc append base=lib.policy_vintage_historical
            data=policy_vintage
            force;
run;
```

If you want to display this in a long format, use `proc transpose`. Note that you will need to either sort or index `policy_vintage` within `lib.policy_vintage_historical` before transposing.

```
proc transpose data   = lib.policy_vintage_historical
               out    = policy_vintage_tpose(drop=_NAME_)
               prefix = Week;
    by policy_vintage;
    id week;
    var Total;
run;
```

Comment: I have a question if the append will work if, for example, in the first week I will have e.g. 2021-11 but in the next week of this month there will be no more records, it will add items to me and put 0 in this row ?

Comment: It will not. You will need to add additional logic, such as a template dataset of all the unique policy vintages. You can set them all to zero by default. If your SQL query has any counts > 0, you can merge it with this dataset and append. Otherwise, you can just append the zero rows. You'll want to do this with macro code (`%if`, `%then`, `%else`).

Comment: I don't know if I understood it correctly, how I can do it with macros. are You able to give me an example ?

Comment: There is a special macro variable called `&sqlobs` that tells you how many values were selected from the last sql query. You could do something like `%if(&sqlobs. > 0) %then %do; <merge data with template of 0 values per policy_vintage>; %end; proc append ...` You'll have it always append a dataset, whether it's zero values or non-zero values. I recommend looking into some of the examples of how to use macros on the SAS help site, or start a new question. This comment section is not made to give code examples.